# Copy files to another package folder (root, su)

Tags: android, root, chmod, su

I have my application's package (com.my.package) and i'd like to be able to copy some files (a.txt, b.txt and c.txt) to another package (data/data/com.another.package/files). Now i've tried a few things i found, but none worked. Any help please?

Answer (score 7):

You need to get the Runtime and use the `cat` command.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su cat filepath1 > filepath2");
```

Comment: @DavidCowden A while back I was making a root app, and I never got those two to work with some of the su binaries. `cat` worked on every binary I tried with, so I'd rather recommend it than `mv` or `cp`

Comment: i get a toast like this http://i50.tinypic.com/10s6atv.png toast, but nothing actually happens. my actually code is Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su cat ro.pca.dragracing_moneyrp/files/111.txt > data/data/com.creativemobile.DragRacing/files");

Comment: cat creates me an empty file; cp and mv don't work also and i don't get any error.

Answer (score 4):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su cat filepath1 > filepath2");
```

creates an empty file for me too. I have to use `su -c` instead

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c cat filepath1 > filepath2");
```