# Android: copy a file to another package as root

Tags: java, android, root, file-manager

I'm facing an issue while writing an app I need for personal use, and I can't find a solution to it.

I need to take a copy of a binary file from an other application, and after some time I need to restore it. The file is taken from /data/data/app.package/files/, so I should not be able to read/write it without root.

I was able to copy the file to an other location using a file explorer, however I'm not able to copy it back with root shell. If I use a file explorer, the file is read again by the app... if I use my code, the original app says that there is data corruption
I've tried several approaches:

cp [origin] [destination] -> file created, but unable to read. 
cp -p [origin] [destination] -> now the permissions seems valid, however it still does not work

cat [origin] > [destination] , and after I manually did chown to set the user and group to the correct one (instead of root) -> still no luck
(taken from here: [Copy files to another package folder (root, su)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886744/copy-files-to-another-package-folder-root-su) )

All of them used this code:

```
Process suProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(suProcess.getOutputStream());
    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
            InputStreamReader(suProcess.getInputStream()));
    for(String command: inputCommands){
        Log.d("ROOT","Writing: " + command);
        os.writeBytes(command+"\n");
    }

    os.writeBytes("exit\n");
    os.flush();
    int suProcessRetval = suProcess.waitFor();
    /* This part is usually outside the method, 
    I copied it here to show how I access the output.
    String aLine = null;

    while ((aLine = stdInput.readLine() )!= null){
        Log.d("ROOT", aLine);
    }
    */
    os.close();
```

is there a way to do it? or maybe any ideas that could help me investigating on this?

Thank you!